# is $f(x)= |{\sin x \over x}|$ uniformly continuous in $(-1,0) \cup (0,1) $?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

is $f(x)= |{\sin x \over x}|$ uniformly continuous in $(-1,0) \cup (0,1) $?

theorem : let   $ f:(a,b) \to \Bbb{R}$ is  continuous  function and limits : $ lim _ {x \to a^+} f(x) $  and $ lim _ {x \to b^-} f(x) $ are exist , then f is uniformly continuous on (a,b)

if we use above theorem $f(x)= |{\sin x \over x}|$ is uniformly continuous in (-1,0) and (0,1) .then f is uniformly continuous in $(-1,0) \cup (0,1) $

is this way true ?

Comment: Look also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687121/the-function-is-continuous-but-not-uniformly-continuous-at-0-1-cup-1-2?rq=1).

Comment: That function is NOT continuous on 0.

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis: Huh???... Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

Define $g:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ by
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}1, &\textrm{if }|x|=0\\
\tfrac{\sin x}{x},&\textrm{if }0<|x|<1\\
 \sin 1, &\textrm{if }|x|=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $g$ is a continuous function on a compact set, so is uniformly continuous.

Since $f$ is a restriction of $g$, it is uniformly continuous as well.

Comment: f is not continuous on 0 though

Answer (score 0):

Your function $f$ can be extended to
$$f(x):=\int_0^1\cos(tx)\>dt\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ ,$$
and is Lipschitz-continuous, hence uniformly continuous, on all of ${\mathbb R}$:
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\int_0^1|\cos(tx)-\cos(ty)|\>dt\leq\int_0^1 t|x-y|\>dt={1\over2}|x-y|\ .$$